# how to query WooCommerce products by date_modified

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce

i am trying to query products by date_modified, to find all the products i did not updated today.

this is the product query :

[image]

this is what i have tried so far :

```
$limit = 400;
    $products_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        => ['product','product_variation'],
        'numberposts'      => $limit,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array( array(
            'key'     => 'date_modified',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            'value'   => '2022-11-17',
        ) )
    ) );
    print_r($products_ids);
```

Comment: If date_modified type is timestamp you need to put the % sign at the end of the value '2022-11-17%' this will match 2022-11-17 00:00:00 up to 2022-11-17 23:59:59.999

Comment: i tried with and without the "%" and still im getting an empty array like Array ( )

Comment: Dates are not stored in post meta, so meta query won't work. You need to use `date_query` here, check the date query details here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters